# Some help with comprehending a text

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, translation

''According to a Gnostic legend, a war broke out in heaven among the angels, in which Michael’s legions defeated those of the Dragon. The nonpartisan angels who had been content to look on were consigned to earth, in order to make there a choice they had not been able to determine on high, **one all the more arduous** in that they brought with them no memory of the combat or, indeed, of their equivocal attitude.''

E. M. Cioran, *Drawn and Quartered*

I've got this text from above, and, given the fact that, obviously, I'm not a native, I have quite a hard time comprehending it. I don't understand, precisely, the words in bold, I mean, individually I do understand them all, but in this context I just can't come up with a correlation between them. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: I found another question which appears to be relevant. If that doesn't answer this one, please edit to be more specific about what it is that you don't understand, and the question will go into a queue to be re-opened.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question to the one cited above. That question is only asking what "all the more" means, This question is asking for the meaning of an entire phrase, one that only includes "all the more"

Comment: **One** is the choice.

If this choice had been made with full knowledge of the battle about to take place it would have been **arduous.** After all it is a choice about the *EXISTENCE.*

Because the choice now has to made by those angels without knowing the context, the choice is **all-the-more** (meaning 'very much more') **arduous** difficult and hard work.

Comment: @Hugh I understand. But then again, '' in order to make there a choice'' - what choice? One of their choices on earth, the place where they were sent?

Comment: They were "non-partisan" angels; that means they did not make up their minds whose side they were on. My reading is that they had to make up their minds (without knowing fully what the situation was) whether to join "Michael and his Angels," or remain forever in ignorance, or, of course, join in on the wrong side and expect to be thrown into the pit.

Comment: @Antonio Nanu **Determine** here means 'to be clear and decisive in their choice.' Previously, on high, they had been *nonpartisan,* they had shown an *equivocal attitude,* they had failed to take the big decision.